# Cart Rules for tiered promotion with exclusions

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to run a simple rule based on cart subtotal. If itfalls between 2 amounts, a $ discount gets applied.

The problem starts when I need to set conditions about what items can be "counted" towards this subtotal. I.e, certain items are to be excluded.

I can't seem to get this to work. Is it even possible? I defined conditions under "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)." but it did not do what I want.